# Angular 6 - Clicking on a table row after filtering returns wrong values

Tags: angular, angular6

This is a generic question - I have a table with clickable rows. Upon click, the user is taken to another page and shows some more data. Of course, this data depends on which row is clicked. This functionality works fine before a filter action is done on the table. After a filter is done, clicking on the same row does not return the correct data. The question is, does the index change after filter, as a result affecting what data is being shown in the next page? If required, I can post some snippets, but I think it may be down to the index.

```
<div class="cell small-2">
          <div class="row">
            <h6 class="text-justify"
                style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 8px;text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 500;">
              Venue
            </h6>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="sessionFilter.session_location_venue" placeholder="Filter"
                   style="margin-top: 7px; margin-left: 1px; text-transform: uppercase" maxlength="34">

          </div>
        </div>
```

This is one of the filters.

```
<app-session-item
      *ngFor="let sessionEl of sessions | filterBy: sessionFilter; let i = index"
      [session]="sessionEl" [index]="sessions.length - i - 1">
    </app-session-item>
```

The filter function:

```
sessionFilter: any = {
session_location_venue: ''
```

};

Comment: Yes, the index value is changed according to the applied filter. And please provide some code so that we can help you.

Comment: It is hard to say without code. You can create a stackblitz example to reproduce your behavior

Comment: you should never work with indices like this, just rely on an .id or key property on the row object

Comment: I have updated the question with some code. The code is from someone else so I am not sure if you have everything you need, please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @StepUp any inputs you may have are very welcome and appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, you are right, your rows can have different index based on the filter value. For example, you have the following rows:

```
[
     {value: 'a', id: 1}, // index: 0
     {value: 'b', id: 2}, // index: 1
     {value: 'c', id: 3}, // index: 2
     {value: 'd', id: 4}, // index: 3
     {value: 'e', id: 5}  // index: 4
]
```

Then, you've applied a filter which gets only rows with `value: 'e'`. Now you have another index:

```
[
     {value: 'e', id: 5}  // index: 0
]
```

So you should not rely on index. You should rely on something relyable, e.g. `id`.